# Check argument passed to a shell script is an URL

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

How do I check if the argument passed to a shell script is an url starting with http or https and endes with .jpg?

I'have the following code to check, but this only check if argument has benn passed.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$S1" ]
then
   echo "Missing JPG URL"
fi
```

Comment: The real answer is, bash can't do this. The accepted answer gets close enough for an internally-used script or something, but would not fly in a publicly distributed utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the pattern-matching operator:

```
if [[ $1 != http?(s)://*.jpg ]]; then
    echo "Invalid URL"
fi
```

(You may need to enable extended patterns with `shopt -s extglob` first in older versions of `bash`.)

Alternatively, use a regular expression:

```
if ! [[ $1 =~ https?://.*\.jpg ]]; then
```

Comment: I run the script with ./shelscriptjpg http://www.example.com/test.jpg but still give me the echo Invalid URL.

Comment: If you want to check the first argument, use `$1`, not `$S1`.

Comment: But how about for URL's that start with https?

Comment: Updating answer, but please be sure to put all the details you need in the question, rather updating the criteria here.

Comment: Check your regexp, it returns true when valid, unlike your first example using pattern-matching. Adding a `!` in front of `$1` worked for me.

Comment: @JKL Thanks; I forgot to negate it when moving from `!=` (not `==`) to `=~`. Occasionally, I wish `bash` supported `!~` like Perl.